# как узнать где usb3 на компе?

Tags: linux, usb

у меня на передней панели компьютера один usb и ещё вроде type-c, или нет, я не пойму что за вход. может какой нибудь mini-usb. в общем я купил как то wifi адаптер https://www.tp-link.com/ru/home-networking/adapter/archer-t4u/
но драйвера для его версии на новой ubuntu не компилируются. и я сделал несколько исправлений в соответствии с новым ядром. и вот какой вывод.

```
[  647.230396] WARNING: CPU: 0 PID: 569 at /home/cf/dev/driver/T4Uv3_WiFi_linux_v5.3.1_beta/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:3042 rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xbf/0x106 [88x2bu]
[  647.230398] Modules linked in: 88x2bu(OE) vboxnetadp(OE) vboxnetflt(OE) vboxdrv(OE) nls_iso8859_1 snd_hda_codec_hdmi snd_hda_codec_realtek snd_hda_codec_generic intel_rapl_msr mei_hdcp snd_sof_pci snd_sof_intel_hda_common snd_soc_hdac_hda snd_sof_intel_hda snd_sof_intel_byt snd_sof_intel_ipc snd_sof snd_sof_xtensa_dsp snd_hda_ext_core snd_soc_acpi_intel_match snd_soc_acpi ledtrig_audio snd_soc_core snd_compress ac97_bus snd_pcm_dmaengine snd_hda_intel snd_usb_audio snd_intel_dspcfg snd_hda_codec snd_usbmidi_lib snd_hda_core mc intel_rapl_common snd_hwdep x86_pkg_temp_thermal snd_pcm intel_powerclamp coretemp snd_seq_midi joydev cfg80211 snd_seq_midi_event kvm_intel input_leds snd_rawmidi snd_seq kvm snd_seq_device snd_timer crct10dif_pclmul ghash_clmulni_intel cryptd rapl intel_cstate i915 snd wmi_bmof mei_me drm_kms_helper soundcore mei i2c_algo_bit fb_sys_fops syscopyarea sysfillrect sysimgblt intel_pch_thermal ie31200_edac acpi_pad mac_hid acpi_tad sch_fq_codel parport_pc ppdev lp
[  647.230450]  parport drm ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_generic uas usb_storage usbhid hid crc32_pclmul i2c_i801 r8169 ahci realtek libahci wmi video [last unloaded: 88x2bu]
[  647.230468] CPU: 0 PID: 569 Comm: kworker/0:5 Tainted: G        W  OE     5.4.0-47-generic #51-Ubuntu
[  647.230470] Hardware name: Acer Aspire XC-885/Aspire XC-885, BIOS R01-B4 04/09/2019
[  647.230478] Workqueue: usb_hub_wq hub_event
[  647.230582] RIP: 0010:rtw_os_ndevs_register+0xbf/0x106 [88x2bu]
[  647.230587] Code: 87 36 48 00 00 49 8d b6 20 34 00 00 84 c0 74 0d 49 8d b6 30 34 00 00 3c 01 49 0f 45 f7 e8 5a f1 ff ff 41 89 c5 83 f8 01 74 b0 <0f> 0b 85 db 75 15 48 63 db 49 8b bc dc 50 01 00 00 48 85 ff 74 05
[  647.230589] RSP: 0018:ffffb3e240877790 EFLAGS: 00010297
[  647.230592] RAX: 0000000000000000 RBX: 0000000000000000 RCX: ffff8ab412f6d060
[  647.230594] RDX: ffff8ab412f6d060 RSI: 0000000000000000 RDI: ffffb3e2400b25b0
[  647.230595] RBP: ffffb3e2408777c0 R08: 0000000000000000 R09: 0000000000000009
[  647.230597] R10: 0000000000000031 R11: ffff8ab41da299e0 R12: ffff8ab412f68000
[  647.230599] R13: 0000000000000000 R14: ffffb3e2400af000 R15: ffffffffc101e793
[  647.230602] FS:  0000000000000000(0000) GS:ffff8ab41da00000(0000) knlGS:0000000000000000
[  647.230604] CS:  0010 DS: 0000 ES: 0000 CR0: 0000000080050033
[  647.230606] CR2: 00007fe53402b218 CR3: 000000017c00a006 CR4: 00000000003606f0
[  647.230608] Call Trace:
[  647.230714]  rtw_os_ndevs_init+0x29/0x3d [88x2bu]
[  647.230813]  rtw_drv_init+0x4e4/0x606 [88x2bu]
[  647.230821]  usb_probe_interface+0xed/0x290
[  647.230826]  really_probe+0x2b3/0x3e0
[  647.230829]  driver_probe_device+0xbc/0x100
[  647.230833]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[  647.230837]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[  647.230843]  bus_for_each_drv+0x84/0xd0
[  647.230846]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[  647.230851]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[  647.230853]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[  647.230858]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[  647.230862]  ? _cond_resched+0x19/0x30
[  647.230867]  usb_set_configuration+0x433/0x7d0
[  647.230873]  ? kernfs_activate+0x77/0x80
[  647.230879]  generic_probe+0x43/0x60
[  647.230883]  usb_probe_device+0x31/0x70
[  647.230886]  really_probe+0x2b3/0x3e0
[  647.230889]  driver_probe_device+0xbc/0x100
[  647.230893]  __device_attach_driver+0x71/0xd0
[  647.230896]  ? driver_allows_async_probing+0x50/0x50
[  647.230901]  bus_for_each_drv+0x84/0xd0
[  647.230904]  __device_attach+0xe1/0x160
[  647.230908]  device_initial_probe+0x13/0x20
[  647.230910]  bus_probe_device+0x8f/0xa0
[  647.230915]  device_add+0x3c7/0x6b0
[  647.230919]  ? add_device_randomness+0xa0/0x1c0
[  647.230925]  usb_new_device.cold+0x12d/0x304
[  647.230930]  hub_port_connect+0x500/0x850
[  647.230935]  port_event+0x502/0x780
[  647.230940]  ? __switch_to_asm+0x34/0x70
[  647.230946]  hub_event+0x152/0x390
[  647.230952]  process_one_work+0x1eb/0x3b0
[  647.230957]  worker_thread+0x4d/0x400
[  647.230962]  kthread+0x104/0x140
[  647.230966]  ? process_one_work+0x3b0/0x3b0
[  647.230969]  ? kthread_park+0x90/0x90
[  647.230973]  ret_from_fork+0x35/0x40
[  647.230978] ---[ end trace f31c7556f17c78c5 ]---
[  647.230983] RTW: rtw_wdev_free(wdev=00000000038d11b7)
[  647.230987] RTW: rtw_wiphy_free(phy3)
[  647.231002] RTW: rtw_usb_primary_adapter_deinit((null))
[  647.231003] RTW: rtw_dev_unload: bup==_FALSE
[  647.231368] RTW: +r871xu_dev_remove, hw_init_completed=0
[  647.231558] RTW: WARN free_recv_skb_queue not empty, 8
[  647.231588] RTW: usb attached..., try to reset usb device
[  647.358568] usb 1-7: reset high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
```

драйвер как бы скомпилировался вроде нормально и нужно понять, может теперь дело в usb? как мне определить подключен usb3 или нет?

Answer (score 1):

> как мне определить подключен usb3 или нет?

*lsusb* - что бы получить список всех USB устройств, включенных в систему.

*s /dev | grep usb* - что бы посмотреть список устройств в каталоге /dev

*ls -l /run/media/<Ваш логин>/* - что бы узнать, какие из них смонтированы

Comment: в дев сейчас не монтируется usbfs по умолчанию

Comment: @eri В разных дистрибутивах по разному.  К примеру, на федоре монтируется в */run/media/<login>*

Comment: А причем тут флешки?

Comment: @eri -"А причем тут флешки?"

- При том, что если я воткну флэшку в USB порт, то она смонтируется в эту папку.

Answer (score 1):

xhci_hcd - это протокол USB3

usb 1-7 - это номер порта в материнке